# How to send array of data to Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: java, javascript, android, arrays, parse-platform

I'm trying to send an array of contact emails (strings) in the Parse cloud code function parameter. I'm doing it like this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> params = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.add("contact email 1");
array.add("contact email 2");
array.add("contact email 3");

params.put("contacts", array);

ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("cloudFunctionName", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void done(Object o, ParseException e) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

I define my cloud function here:
`contacts` should be something like: `{"contacts" : ["contact email 1", "contact email 2", "contact email 3"]}`. I iterate of each of the emails and perform some logic with each.

```
var _ = require("underscore");

Parse.Cloud.define("cloudFunctionName", function (request, response) {
var contacts = request.params.contacts;

_.each(contacts, function(contactEmail) {
    var userQuery = Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    userQuery.equalTo("email", contactEmail);

    userQuery.first().then(
        function(user) {
            // there is a user with that email
        },
        function(error) {
            // no user found with that email
});
```

});

The problem I'm getting is that sometimes contactEmail is undefined.

I get the error: `Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'equalTo' of undefined` on the line userQuery.equalTo("email", contactEmail);

Even if I write `if(typeof contactEmail != "undefined") { userQuery.equalTo("email", contactEmail); }`, I still get the error.

I also check that the emailString is not empty before adding it to the array?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your JavaScript to create the Users query like this:

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
```